# converting JS variable to string & display it in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im newbie in JS so please bear with me.

I have a JS variable that i got from web service (JSON type). I tried to alert this variable and its **working**, returning 1 (integer) :

```
alert(result[0].totalMall);
```

I want to add a string to this variable so it will become like (for example) : 1 mall(s)

This is my code :

```
var result = result[0].totalMall.toString() + "Mall(s)";
                        alert(result);
                        $('.totalMall', this).html(result);
```

But the alert above always returning **undefined**. What should i do? I have been working for hours to just fix this.

And the result always displaying just "mall(s)" without the integer (`result[0].totalMall.toString()`) with it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: It may be having problems with the fact that you have two things named `result`.  Try `var res = result[0].totalMall.toString() + "Mall(s)";`, and see if that's any better.  (Then `alert(res)` etc, of course.)

Comment: Your code doesn't match your described results, and in fact it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/cr5ud/. Can you post a fiddle that reproduces the issue? I think you may be having an issue with the fact that you are overwriting your `result` variable (though it doesn't affect the code you've posted).

Comment: try without `.toString()` sum of integer and string always returns string :)

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
var results = [
  {
    totalMall :3
  },
  {
    totalMall :5
  }
];

var result = results[0].totalMall.toString() + " Mall(s)";
alert(result);
$("#div").html(result);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WaydY/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, all :D

yes, it appears that "something" was wrong last night. I tried the code this morning, and its working fine now :D